# Forward Geocoding with Swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, geocoding

I am looking to be able to have a user input an address, and be able to save that address, and convert it into latitude and longitudinal coordinates. I haven't been able to find much documentation on forward geocoding, and I am having trouble starting this code. Should I ask the user to input the address by (city, state, zip code)? Or would a single address suffice? Is there a function that can do what I need? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simple [LocationManager](https://github.com/RajanMaheshwari/LocationManager) helper on github in which you can get the thing what you want.

There is a function `getReverseGeoCodedLocation` in the library. Just input your address as a String and get the complete placemark and lat, longs.

Add the `LocationManager.swift` file in your project

How to use it:-

```
LocationManager.sharedInstance.getReverseGeoCodedLocation(address: yourAddress, completionHandler: { (location:CLLocation?, placemark:CLPlacemark?, error:NSError?) in

        if error != nil {
            print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        if placemark == nil {
            print("Location can't be fetched")
            return
        }

        print(placemark?.addressDictionary?.description ?? "")
        print((placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
        print((placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

})
```

Internally it uses the `geocodeAddressString` of `CLGeocoder`

Output

[image]
**Note**:- It is for Swift 3.0 and above

Comment: Hi @Rajan Maheshwari, the code you posted on github is exactly what I was looking for! However, I inputed the LocationManager.swift file into my project, and used the above code, inputing the address variable into yourAddress, however, when I try to convert it, it does not print anything (not even the errors). Do you have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @Kevin What are you entering in address String and which xcode version are you using?

Comment: Also use a debugger whether it is coming inside the completion block or not? I just wrote New Delhi in the textView and it printed the complete lat long and address

Comment: I just tested it with the string "New York City" for the address variable. I am also using Swift 3.0. How do I use a debugger inside the code?

Comment: I also did the same and posted the screenshot. Check the edit in my answer. You should be connected to internet

Comment: Visit https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html on how to use debugger

Comment: @Kevin Just download the complete github project and run it. Press custom address string button and enter your string there and check. Its working fine

Comment: I made some modifications to your code to match my app. Instead of the textView that you used to input the city (addressTextView.text), I changed that to a global variable that has an address location from another view controller. Could this be the cause of it not working?

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. You just have to pass a simple string to that helper method in whatever way you like to. Only make sure it is not empty. If it is empty it will show `Reverse Geocoding Failed`

Comment: I think your code has worked, but somehow the output (a print statement) is being suppressed, because other print statements aren't showing up, but I know they are working. This has solved my question, thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Kevin Thanks!. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the paid Google Maps API (for commercial purposes) and usage of CLLocation you can also take a look at NominatimSwift: https://github.com/caloon/NominatimSwift 
It's probably the most lightweight solution if you just want to geocode. 
(Disclaimer: I made it)

NominatimSwift uses the free Nominatim API for geocoding of OpenStreetMap data. You can also search for landmarks. It requires network connectivity.

Geocoding addresses and landmarks:

```
Nominatim.getLocation(fromAddress: "The Royal Palace of Stockholm", completion: {(error, location) -> Void in
  print("Geolocation of the Royal Palace of Stockholm:")
  print("lat = " + (location?.latitude)! + "   lon = " + (location?.longitude)!)
})
```

Reverse geocoding:

```
Nominatim.getLocation(fromLatitude: "55.6867243", longitude: "12.5700724", completion: {(error, location) -> Void in
  print("City for geolocation 55.6867243/12.5700724:")
  print(location?.city)
})
```